# Low quality printing on tall 3D models

Tags: 3d-models, flashprint, flashforge-dreamer

I have the FlashForge Dreamer NX which prints with good quality on small models. However, when the model is taller than 2 cm or 2.5 cm (around 0.8 or 1 inch), it really loses quality.

Here there is a picture so you can understand what I mean. Which setting do I have to change? Have a look the the base is very acceptable, but then, the printing is not acceptable.

[image: Printed model losing quality the higher up it is printed]

I'm using FlashPrint 5, but I can switch to any other app if it is needed.

**UPDATE**

I'm using PLA 1.75. Here are my settings.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Settings look okay, except for a very thick first layer of 0.4 mm and an extrusion width of 2 mm (not related to your problem), you should look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 4):

The cause of the meshing is under-extrusion. When under-extrusion happens, several problems can cause this. E.g. heat creep (probably not the issue here because heat creep is usually not recoverable, but not unimaginable since this is an enclosed printer, you could try printing at a lower temperature and look into less aggressive retraction settings), or an extrusion problem.

Since this is an intermittent, recurring defect, this could typically be a result of spool entanglement or any other defect in the extrusion path. Once the entanglement or friction on the spool has resolved itself, the print continues as if nothing happened.

You should print again and look at what happens. Also pay attention to the extruder, it may be skipping steps or hasn't got enough force to push the filament through.

Check the extrusion of filament also by disconnecting the extruder and manually feeding the filament through a hot nozzle. It should be easy to push the filament through the nozzle at temperature. If not, try cleaning the nozzle doing a cold/atomic pull (feed filament hot, cut the power to the hotend, wait until the temperature drops considerably and suddenly pull out the filament, preferably with nylon or cleaning filament or any other high temperature filament).

Answer (score 1):

That looks horribly familiar; I call it meshing.

It's underextrusion, which can be caused by lots of things.

I cleaned, then replaced the hot end, Bowden tube, and both couplers trying to solve the problem, but then the Z axis was binding.  Tried a couple things for that, what seems to have worked was loosening a couple of screws flanking the Z screw.  Prints are still coming out a little short, so I think I'll have to shim the Z screw brace.